# updating static files in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I have a welcome page (JSP file) for my application that contains some dynamic content.
e.g. recent posts links, most active categories etc.

To make this work I need to make some data store queries that return these data. this is pretty much unoptimized. especially in the home page and makes its loading time big as compared to hard coding these links in the JSP file.

I am thinking of updating the static JSP file every day with latest data by using a cron task. thus, actually generating a JSP file and replacing the old one. Do you think this is possible? I am also open to any ideas!

thanks;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do it because on Google App Engine [secure sandbox environment](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) an application cannot write to the filesystem.
In order to improve the homepage's performance consider to cache the db results in [memcache](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/memcache/).

Answer (score 0):

This is how the BBC's website has run for many years.  Normally the benefit provided by dynamic generation outweighs the cost.

Article discussing relatively recent changes to the BBC news site incorporating dynamic content:

http://paulrobertlloyd.com/2010/09/bbc_news_redesign

Comment: Have you done this on google app engine, or know how to do this? I have done this before on a normal tomcat server.

Comment: Cron jobs are available in App Engine: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html

Comment: @mmohab You could always have a job that renders the page, or parts of the page, to HTML every hour or day, or whatever, store the rendered HTML in memcache and the datastore.  Then you'll be able to fetch the page with a single batch fetch (based on key, not query) from memcache and/or the datastore.