# How can I upload a static HTML to templates folder of GAE app?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

Can I upload a static HTML file to templates folder without re-deploying the app?

Offline I create an HTML file which I want to upload to my Google app engine app,which displays the HTML as per URLs. But I don't want to deploy my site every time I am uploading a new file.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: In short you can't do it.. possible duplicate of [updating static files in google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561522/updating-static-files-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: But you can upload templates and load templates from the datastore.

Comment: Thanks @voscausa, datastore solution sounds great.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant if you want to store them in static storage.
You can store them somewhere non-static but you will lose the many advantages of having it as static content.

Comment: Or advantages. U use Jinja templates which have been compiled to Python modules, loaded from the datastore but most of the time making use of the app engine instance module cache.